# Quotes within quotes - as a string?

Tags: php

I have a PHP string:

```
$str = '';
```

I need to have some HTML in this, but the HTML has 'quotes within quotes'. How would one deal with the situation?

The HTML is:

```
data-setup="{'example_option':true}"
```

Comment: use "\" character for escaping Quotes

Comment: Is the format of the html known before hand?

Comment: If you don't want to have any escaping issue you can use heredocs. They're not very comfort, but if you have a static long string to parse they may become a good solution. In your case, however, it is just enough to escape each `"` by adding a backslash before it: `\"` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with quotes inside quotes, you need to escape them like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"somelink.html\">Link</a>";
```

simply put:

```
\" tells php to simply echo out the " as a quote instead of handling it as a part of the code.
```

Your string:

```
$string = "data-setup=\"{'example_option':true}\""
echo $string;
// Output:
data-setup="{'example_option':true}"
```

Comment: Could you show me an example with my code, I've tired escaping it, but it still fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `HEREDOC`

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOD
        data-setup="{'example_option':true}"
EOD;

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to pass some data from PHP to a view through the `data-attribute`. I would recommend you use `json_encode` and build you're data as a normal PHP array rather than worrying about escaping quotes or other nasty stuff.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            $data = array(
                  'example_option' => true,
                  'some_html'      => '<b>"Hello & good day!"</b>',
                );

            // avoid escaping from the JS parser
            $str = json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
            ?>

        <a data-setup='<?php echo $str; ?>' href="#">This link has awesome data</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can just access access the data attribute very easily (I did make a big assumption here that you are using jQuery).

[image]